# SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network

Tags: cpp-ethereum, sepolia, safe

I am trying to send ETH from my safe wallet.

Safe address : 0x159bD467fafcfA348D2b5f357b23aA1d70E814A0

.proposeTransaction({
safeAddress: checksumSafeAddresss,
safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
safeTxHash,
senderAddress: await owner1Signer.getAddress(),
senderSignature: senderSignature.data,
});
I am getting the error "SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network"

On Sepolia Network.

Note : I am doing it using code not using UI of safe.